# Datatable Footer Row Not Displaying at Correct Position

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a datatable with 32 columns and enabled horizontal scroll. I want to display total for integer columns in footer. I have tried I am getting total in footer but the footer row is displaying outside of horizontal scroll. Could it be displayed inside scroll below the column ?

Screenshot:
[image]

**Code:**

```
strEdit += "<tfoot><tr><th colspan='15'></th><th class='totaldisplay'><div class='totalcol1'><i class='fa fa-gbp'></i>" + addCommas(deveffortTotal) + "</div></th> <th colspan='16'></th> </tr></tfoot>"; // 32 Columns
```

**Datatable feature:**

```
$j('#GridView').append(HTML);
            if ($j('#GridView').find("table").length > 0) {
                $j('#GridView').find("table").DataTable({
                    scrollY: "400px",
                    scrollX: true,
                    scrollCollapse: true,
                    paging: true,
                    fixedColumns: {
                        leftColumns: 1,
                        rightColumns: 2
                    },
                    "columnDefs": [{
                        "targets": 'no-sort',
                        "orderable": false,
                    }],
                    dom: 'lrtip'                    
                });
            }
            else {
                $j('#GridView').empty();
                HTML = ''; strEdit = '';
                strEdit = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>No record found.</div>";
                HTML = HTML + strEdit; $j('#GridView').append(HTML);
            }
```

**CSS:**

```
.totalcol1 {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
.totaldisplay {
    background-color: #4A4A4A !important;
    color: #ffffff;
}

tfoot tr th {
    border-color: transparent !important;    
}
```